# Need SQL query for hierarchical data in a flat result set

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, recursive-query

There's a table: PS_POSITION_TBL

```
position_nbr      reports_to              descr        
 038              143                     DIRECTOR 
 0418             143                     ADVISOR                        
 114              143                     DG                              
 346              114                     Manager                        
 202              114                     Lead
```

The idea we want to build a hierarchy in above

case 1: 038 ,0418 and 114 reports to  143

case 2: 346 and 202 reports to 114

so highest level is level1 which is 143 then 038,0418,114 are level 2 as they report to level 1 then 346 and 202 are level 3 and they fall under
level 3 bucket and they report to level 2

These can go up to level 8 (MAX)

What I need is a query to get data in the below format in Oracle:

```
level1  level2   level3  level4 level5 level6 level7 level8      descr
 143                                                             CEO            
           038                                                   DIRECTOR        
           0418                                                  ADVISOR         
           114                                                   DG              
                    346                                          Manager         
                    202                                          Lead
```

Comment: Position 143 is not in your table.  How do you know what the `descr` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select    level1,level2,level3,level4,level5,level6,level7,level8,descr

from     (select        level as n,position_nbr as id,descr,position_nbr

          from          (         select position_nbr ,reports_to ,descr from PS_POSITION_TBL 
                        union all select 143          ,null       ,'CEO' from dual
                        )  t

          start with    reports_to is null

          connect by    reports_to = prior position_nbr
          ) 
          pivot (max(position_nbr) for n in (1 as level1,2 as level2,3 as level3,4 as level4,5 as level5,6 as level6,7 as level7,8 as level8))
;
```

or

```
select    decode (n,1,position_nbr) as level1
         ,decode (n,2,position_nbr) as level2
         ,decode (n,3,position_nbr) as level3
         ,decode (n,4,position_nbr) as level4
         ,decode (n,5,position_nbr) as level5
         ,decode (n,6,position_nbr) as level6
         ,decode (n,7,position_nbr) as level7
         ,decode (n,8,position_nbr) as level8
         ,descr

from     (select          level as n,position_nbr,descr

          from          (         select position_nbr ,reports_to ,descr from PS_POSITION_TBL 
                      union all select 143          ,null       ,'CEO' from dual
                      )  t

          start with    reports_to is null

          connect by    reports_to = prior position_nbr
          ) 
;
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but it hardcodes 143 instead of finding it from the data. 143 can be found by, for example, selecting distinct from reports_to which are not in position_nbr.

Comment: @mathguy, you are just guessing, as i did. You don't know that 143 is not in position_nbr (and you are not going to get the description like this)

Comment: If 143 is in position_nbr, then it is not Level 1, is it? That is the whole point! And the description should be left NULL; what the OP shows in the output is nowhere in the input data or the problem requirement. (It could be put in the latter, e.g. "for Level 1 id's, which do not have a description, hard-code 'CEO' for description.")

Comment: @mathguy, not at all. 143 might be in position_nbr **and** in level 1, if reports_to is for example NULL. Since this issue is not clear, I have presented a solution that solves the question according to the given data.

Comment: @jujadhav, does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give you a hierarchical set, left-padded by `LEVEL`:

```
SELECT LPAD(' ', level * 2, ' ') || TO_CHAR(position_nbr), descr
  FROM PS_POSITION_TBL
CONNECT BY PRIOR position_nbr = reports_to
START WITH reports_to IS NULL;
```

If you're not satisfied with displaying the level in a single column (`LEVEL`) and  need a column for each level, you can use [PIVOT](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1) based on `LEVEL` but it will make the ordering problematic.